# Death of Ravana, his Karma or Destiny?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

On the battlefield when Rama shot an arrow to kill Ravana, Laxman was directed by Rama to go and get his best advice.

1. The first thing Raavan told Lakshman was that one should complete any auspicious work as soon as possible and keep delaying the inauspicious work as much as possible.
2. The second thing he taught Lakshman was never to underestimate one’s enemy. He said that he did this mistake of understanding the monkeys and bears lesser or incompetent and he lost the battle against them.
3. The third and final thing Raavan told Lakshman that one should not reveal one’s life secret to anyone in the world. Raavan made a mistake as Vibhishan knew the secret of his death. Raavan knew this was his biggest mistake in life.

So, my concern is if Ravana knew all this, then what led him to his defeat and ultimate death on the battlefield.

**Was it his Destiny or Karma?**